# Can't install PyQt5 using pip on alpine docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine AS app

RUN apk update && apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev gfortran openblas-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /srv
```

When I connect to my container and I launch: `pip install pyqt5`

I got error:

```
$ pip install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7am47sr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7am47sr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7am47sr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-p2ogfk1p/pyqt5_97a9414aa7ba410f9715856d348d62b4/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7am47sr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7am47sr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7am47sr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Do you have qmake installed?

Comment: @KevinWoodward I do not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PyQt5 Pypi project](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) requires that `qmake` can be found (emphasis mine):

> pip will also build and install the bindings from the sdist package but **Qt’s qmake tool must be on PATH**.

This can be done by installing e.g. `qt5-qtbase-dev`, potentially together [with other packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=qt5-*&branch=edge&repo=&arch=x86_64&maintainer=). Then the `qmake` command can be found in the path. (If not, it can be added this way: `export PATH=/usr/lib/qt5/bin:$PATH`)

So, this should work on the docker container:

```bash
apk add qt5-qtbase-dev
pip install --no-cache-dir pyqt5
```

*(`--no-cache-dir` can save memory usage. But the installation is still quite long and memory intensive.)*

Honestly, I haven't managed to install this on my computer with 32GB RAM. The installation step is quite heavy under Alpine Docker and easily leads to OOM. Sadly, there are no pre-compiled sources available (at least not in pypi): https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files

```bash
pip install PyQt5-5.15.9-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl
ERROR: PyQt5-5.15.9-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

If you do not find wheel files for Alpine from other locations and have not enough RAM to build yourself, I simply recommend not using Alpine Linux. Installation seems much simpler under Ubuntu and other distributions like e.g. Debian Bullseye:

```
FROM python:3.11 AS app

RUN apt update && apt install -y make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev gfortran libopenblas-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /srv
```

Then `pip install pyqt5` is no problem.

---

**Remark:** *I am not an expert for qmake. So it is possible that there are better ways instead of installation of `qt5-qtbase-dev`. But at least you will end having `qmake` available in the PATH.*

Answer (score 2):

Try first to add the Qt toolkit, which includes `qmake`.

PyQt5 is a set of Python bindings for the Qt libraries, and so it requires some of the Qt tools to be present in order to build correctly.

In Alpine Linux, the Qt tools are typically available in the [`qt5-qtbase-dev` package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/qt5-qtbase-dev). So you can install it with `apk add`.

Your Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine AS app

RUN apk update && apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev gfortran openblas-dev qt5-qtbase-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /srv
```